# Invalid domain name error when trying to send email with django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, outlook

Please help to resolve this issue:

Facing following error when trying to send email in Django on Ubuntu:

```
env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 92, in open
self.connection.starttls(context=self.ssl_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 769, in starttls
self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/smtplib.py", line 614, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
raise SMTPHeloError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPHeloError: (501, b'5.5.4 Invalid domain name')
```

Email host is Hotmail

Using standard settings for Django:

```
EMAIL_HOST_USERNAME = 'x@hotmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

How to resolve this issue?

Checked email settings for Hotmail
Receiving email without "https/http"
All characters in email address is in lowercase

Comment: The parameter for the email user is called [`EMAIL_HOST_USER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#email-host-user) and not `EMAIL_HOST_USERNAME`.

Comment: Thanks, corrected host user, but still raises same error.

Answer (score 0):

this (501, b'5.5.4 Invalid domain name) error
maybe about the mail server problem.
check it again.

this should be a EMAIL_HOST_USER not EMAIL_HOST_USERNAME
and check this Docs `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#email-host-user`